# file input not work in joomla 2.5 component

Tags: php, components, joomla2.5

I have a simple component that must upload a file to the server, but when submit form I see this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\wamp\www\joomla2.5\components\com_print\print.php on line 13
```

component is in frontend and my code is:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller'); 
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
echo $_POST['uploaded_file'];
echo $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];
?>
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datas for an input of type "file" are in [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) not $_POST

```
var_dump($_FILES['uploaded_file']);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from F.C. is technically correct, you should never directly access PHP Superglobals within Joomla. You should instead use JInput (or the depreceated JRequest) instead.
You can read more about JInput here: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput